# Force landscape mode by maximizing with plyr.io on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, mobile

Hi community I would like to solve a problem, I am currently using plyr.io as a player, the detail is that when you want to watch a video on a cell phone in full screen, the player is maximized in portrait mode, there will be some way that by automatically maximizing it is in landscape mode only on the mobile, even when minimize return to portrait, even if the cell phone is in portrait mode.

### [image: 1]]

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Plyr</title>
  <!-- Plyr style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.5.6/plyr.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Plyr -->
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.5.6/plyr.min.js"></script>

  <video id="player" poster="https://i.imgur.com/YC9U2uc.jpg" controls crossorigin>
  </video>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const player = new Plyr('#player');
  player.source = {
    type: 'video',
    title: 'Sintel',
    sources: [{
        src: '//iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player-with-captions/video/sintel-short.webm',
        type: 'video/mp4',
      }

    ],
    tracks: [{
        kind: 'captions',
        label: 'English',
        srclang: 'en',
        src: '//iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player-with-captions/subtitles/vtt/sintel-en.vtt',
        default: false,
      },
      {
        kind: 'captions',
        label: 'German',
        srclang: 'de',
        src: '//iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player-with-captions/subtitles/vtt/sintel-de.vtt',
      },
    ],
  };
</script>

</html>
```

I have tried with CSS code, but it is not very good, because it only rotates the video, it does not rotate the controls or the poster, which when applied to maximize it applies:

```css
transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.75);
```

I think the best would be with JavaScript,Thank you in advance.

**Source: https://plyr.io/**

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this:

```
screen.orientation.lock('landscape');
```

as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation

Answer (score 2):

plyr.io specific, use `enterfullscreen` and `exitfullscreen` events along with screen orientation:

```js
player.on('enterfullscreen', event => {
    screen.orientation.lock('landscape');
});

player.on('exitfullscreen', event => {
    screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var winwidth=$(window).width();
        var winheight=$(window).height();

        const player = Plyr.setup('#player');
        player.forEach (item => {

            item.on('enterfullscreen', event => {

             $(".plyr__video-wrapper").css({"transform": "rotate(90deg)", "height": winwidth, "width": winheight, "margin-left": "0px", "margin-right": "0px"});
            })
            item.on('exitfullscreen', event => {
             $(".plyr__video-wrapper").css({"transform": "rotate(0deg)", "height": "100%", "width": "100%", "margin-left": "auto", "margin-right": "auto"});
            })
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Listen for the full-screen change event
    document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', () => {
        if (document.fullscreenElement) {
            // Entered full-screen mode, try to lock the screen orientation
            if (screen.orientation && screen.orientation.lock) {
                screen.orientation.lock('landscape').catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error locking screen orientation:', error);
                });
            }
        } else {
            // Exited full-screen mode, try to unlock the screen orientation
            if (screen.orientation && screen.orientation.unlock) {
                screen.orientation.unlock().catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error unlocking screen orientation:', error);
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```